# while creating user for my postgreSQL database. I get error su : The term 'su' is not recognized

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2, su, postgresql-12

I run the following command in my windows powerShell

su postgres

su : The term 'su' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- su  postgres
- ~~

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (su:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: `su` is a Unix command, short for "switch user". You are obviously reading the documentation for the wrong operating system.

Comment: Thank you for helping me I'm reading a book called django 3 by example in which author doesn't explain for what system this comand is going to use i have no experience with PostgerSQL. Can you help me please  how to do it same in windows, I will give you details what I'm trying to do...

Comment: I just checked out the book and you are right, the author makes a little mistake on that page by not disclosing that the `su` command is for Linux or MacOS only. You can simply use the pgAdmin tool installed with the PostgreSQL for Windows to create a new user (login role) and a database.

Answer (score 1):

As for creating a new user for your PostgreSQL database from the command prompt, try the following instructions:

After finishing the PostgreSQL installation, make sure you check and copy the Installation Directory, in my case, is 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13'.

Then follow 'Mycomputer => properties => advanced system settings=> Environment Variables => System Variables', select 'Path' and click 'Edit', in which you`ll addin path 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin' and 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\lib' and save change.

Next open command prompt:

```
cd C:\
psql --version
```

you`ll see the psql version that installed, with all is set:

```
psql -U Postgres
```

the command above connect you to the Database Superuser: Postgres, after applying the password that you create during the process of installation.

```
psql (13.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

comments above inform you`re connected.
Now create a new user and database in commands:

```
create database yourdatabasename;
create user yourusername with password 'password';
```

Apply your own name and password, and don`t forget the semicolon ';',
you can also check the List of databases:

```
\l
```

The last thing you need to do is to grant privilege for the new database to the new user:

```
grant all on database yourdatabase to yourusername;
```

If you want to connect to the database you`ve just created:

```
\q
```

to exit, and then,

```
psql -d databasename -U username
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in Windows there is no sudo/su command.  The nearest alternative is "run as administrator."

You can do this using the [runas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771525(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) command with an administrator, or alternatively by right-clicking the program in the UI and choosing "run as administrator."

Comment: Thank you for helping me I'm reading a book called django 3 by example in which author doesn't explain for what system this comand is going to use i have no experience with PostgerSQL. Can you help me please  how to do it same in windows, I will give you details what I'm trying to do...   -    I'm trying to add full text search in my blog web application using PostgerSQL, i  installed it and tring to create user in book author use following commands   $Su postgres --- $createuser -dp blog --- $createdb -E utf8 -U blog blog --- if you know what to do or what I'm trying to do please Help me out.